# How to link successive new iteration variable to another function to have the same result using printf

Tags: c, sorting, variables, function-call

As you can see every iteration of this nested for loop produces a random variable

```
    for (twod = 0; twod < i; twod++){    
        rnd = rand() %10;
        printf("%d ", rnd);
        rnd = sortedarray(argc, argv);
        }
```

I need to send those same results of rnd from that nested for loop to another function with function call sortedarray(argc,argv)

Comment: So obvious question : why not `sortedarry(argc, argv, rnd)` ?  If you can’t do that (eg, you don’t own sortedarray), then how is sortedarray currently getting that value?

Comment: what is 'md' and exactly what is the code trying to perform?